# How to fire Onclick event from LinkButton in Gridview resides in updatePanel?

Tags: javascript, c#, gridview, asplinkbutton

I know this might be asked before. My gridview rows are changed according to search filter which fetches data from Database. But when I click on Link button to view data only `Onclientclick` is fired and `onclick` is not firing.

Here's my code :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="Hf" />
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <ContentTemplate>  
     <label>  Show  <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="custom-select custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm"
    ID="RecordSize" AutoPostBack="true" Style="width: 51.75px; height: 30.75px;">
    <asp:ListItem Value="10" Selected="True">10</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="25">25</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="50">50</asp:ListItem>    
      </asp:DropDownList>  entries</label> <asp:Label Style="margin-left: 10px;" runat="server" ID="lblerror" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
    <div id="m_table_1_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
     <label>Search:</label>
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch" type="search" autocomplete="off"
      AutoPostBack="true" MaxLength="20" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm" OnTextChanged="txtSearch_TextChanged" Style="margin-top: -30px; margin-left: 65px; width: 250px;"></asp:TextBox> 
    </div>

     <div class="row" style="display: block;">
      <asp:GridView OnPageIndexChanging="MandateGrid_PageIndexChanging" runat="server"
    ID="MandateGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="MandateGrid_RowDataBound"
    PageSize="5" Style="text-align: center;" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"
    CssClass="table table-striped- table-bordered table-hover table-checkable dataTable no-footer">
    <PagerSettings FirstPageText="<<" LastPageText=">>" Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
    <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" Visible="false">
      <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="LabelID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mandate Status">
      <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton CommandArgument="Select" CommandName="Select" ID="btnView" runat="server" Text="View"
    CssClass="btn m-btn--square" OnClientClick="changeAnchor();" OnClick="btnView_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
      </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField> 
      </asp:GridView>
     </div>

    </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
     </form>
```

This is my javascript function, I'm using it just to retrive current column index which I will need in my method. :

```
function changeAnchor() {            
            $(function () {
                $("[id*=MandateGrid]").find("[id*=btnView]").click(function () {                    
                    var row = $(this).closest("tr");                   
                    var message = "Row Index: " + (row[0].rowIndex - 1);
                    $("#Hf").val(row[0].rowIndex - 1);                    
                    //alert(message);
                    return false;
                });
            });
}
```

Here's my onclick event :-

```
protected void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
        lblerror.Text = "Event Fired";
    }
```

Please let me know if I have to add any other code to this question.

Answer (score 1):

your setup is such that the clientClick handler registers a clickhandler, that clickhandler seems unnecessary for what you appear to be trying to do. (set a hidden field so you can figure out which row was targeted on postback).

Since events are handled after restoring the pages' state, you could just use sender in `btnView_Click` to determine the row on the serverside without resorting to javascript here.

try casting sender to Button and see the wealth of available information in the debugger after removing the `OnClientClick` handler altogether.

More directly, your `changeAnchor` function does not return a function, it registers a function to be ran whenever jquery is ready. that in turn registers a clickHandler on then present html elements that happen to match the button. you shouldn't be doing this, you end up probably registering the same handler for all buttons, every time a button is rendered. The eventual click handler also returns false, which cancels the postback.

Comment: Let's say I canceled OnclientClick Event and I just only put OnClick Event.Can I do that? How ? If I set triggers It says Id associated with could not be found. Any ideas?

Comment: My main purpose is to show information in modal with that button.

Comment: what is "it" and what does Id have to do with anything? how does one set a trigger? do you mean breakpoint? I don't have an old enough asp.net project available to show you in completed code. Maybe you could first choose between doing this bit serverside -or- clientside, instead of a mix thereof.

Comment: No, I mean Let's say, I have a modal with a form. and on Onclick id is sent to db and fatches data and shows into modal. but event is not being fired when clicked. That's what I am asking. I tried debugging but it does not go into debug mode as click is not being fired.

Comment: the click does not fire because you cancel it in javascript, you return false, canceling the postback. Remove the javascript and onClientClick attribute, then debug.

Comment: I removed OnclientClick, Ok I went into Debug Mode but I set lblerror.Text = "Event Fired"; on OnClick but field is not being updated. Any idea how?

Comment: I think there's a language barrier here.

Comment: Meaning? Forget onclientclick I removed it from code, I set only onclick and it fires but does not change the value of field after postback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189254/discussion-between-kris-and-rex-jones).